# Objective-c Classes runtime definition

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Is it possible to define classes at run time in objective-c?
E.g. I receive an XML file, that defines an object and create it and use it in run-time?

Comment: Do you mean declare a whole new class type, with ivars and methods in the XML, or do you mean create instances of a pre-existing class with state (ivars, properties etc.) provided by the XML?

Comment: Even if you could (and you probably can), the real question is if you should...

Comment: Tim, the first option, to create whole new class type.

Comment: Squeegy, it depends on the method if I should... This is why I am interested in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, check this code snippet out, I created a class here, using only C methods, and one protocol definition (for simplicity when making message calls)...

MyCObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol MyCObj_methods<NSObject>

-(NSString *) getString;
-(int) getInt;
+(NSString *) someStaticMethod;

@end

typedef id<MyCObj_methods> MyCObj;
extern Class MyCObj_class;

__attribute__((constructor))
void MyCObj_initialize();

MyCObj MyCObj_alloc(        id self,     SEL _cmd );
MyCObj MyCObj_new(          id self,     SEL _cmd );

NSString *MyCObj_someStaticMethod ( id self, SEL _cmd );

MyCObj MyCObj_init(         MyCObj self, SEL _cmd );
NSString *MyCObj_getString( MyCObj self, SEL _cmd );
int MyCObj_getInt(          MyCObj self, SEL _cmd );
```

MyCObject.m

```
#import "MyCObject.h"
#import <objc/Object.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static Class myStaticClass;
Class MyCObj_class;

typedef struct
{
    Class isa;
    NSString *myString;
    int myInt;
} MyCObj_t;

void MyCObj_initialize(void);

__attribute__((constructor))
void MyCObj_initialize()
{
    MyCObj_class = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "MyCObj", 0);
    objc_registerClassPair(MyCObj_class);

    myStaticClass = object_getClass(MyCObj_class);

    class_addMethod(MyCObj_class, @selector(init),      (IMP)MyCObj_init,        "@@:");
    class_addMethod(MyCObj_class, @selector(getString), (IMP)MyCObj_getString,   "@@:");
    class_addMethod(MyCObj_class, @selector(getInt),    (IMP)MyCObj_getInt,      "i@:");

    class_addMethod(myStaticClass, @selector(alloc),            (IMP)MyCObj_alloc, "@@:");
    class_addMethod(myStaticClass, @selector(new),              (IMP)MyCObj_new,   "@@:");
    class_addMethod(myStaticClass, @selector(someStaticMethod), (IMP)MyCObj_someStaticMethod, "@@:");
}

MyCObj MyCObj_alloc(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return (MyCObj) class_createInstance(MyCObj_class, sizeof(MyCObj_t) - sizeof(Class));
}

MyCObj MyCObj_new(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return (MyCObj) [[MyCObj_class alloc] init];
}

NSString *MyCObj_someStaticMethod(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return @"Some Static Method";
}

MyCObj MyCObj_init(MyCObj self, SEL _cmd)
{
    struct objc_super super = { .receiver = self, .super_class = [NSObject class] };

    if ((self = (MyCObj) objc_msgSendSuper(&super, _cmd)))
    {
        ((MyCObj_t *) self)->myString = @"hello world!";
        ((MyCObj_t *) self)->myInt = 15;
    }

    return self;
}

NSString *MyCObj_getString(MyCObj self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return ((MyCObj_t *) self)->myString;
}

int MyCObj_getInt(MyCObj self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return ((MyCObj_t *) self)->myInt;
}
```

Usage:

```
MyCObj obj = [MyCObj_class new];
NSLog(@"%@ %i %@", [obj getString], [obj getInt], [MyCObj_class someStaticMethod]);
```

Comment: Stop it. You're scaring the kids (by which I mean me) :) +1

Comment: @TimKemp actually, I was just writing this up when I saw this question... The idea of this has always intrigued me, creating classes at runtime, and I wanted to test it out... This can be done with blocks, too, its actually really cool to create objects using blocks like that...

Comment: It's genuinely brilliant. I've been idly curious about how far you could push the runtime binding and selector-driven stuff in Objective C; it turns out to be further than I ever thought. Thanks for the glimpse of the baroque (that's really what this is after all: it's hardly practical but there's a certain beauty in its perversity.)

Comment: Yes, it is... Hopefully, @InfinitePossibilities will realize that doesn't mean you should do it. :) Seriously -- defining classes on the fly to encapsulate data is *probably* the wrong answer.  It might be right, but that'd be seriously rare.

Comment: I don't know... It is interesting to create a framework with this... :)

Comment: @InfinitePossibilities Go for it!  It is a tremendous learning exercise.  In the 90s, it was all about using the dynamic features to bind Objective-C to various languages (I've done Python, Tcl, and wrote my own language over the years).  Now? Generic XML encapsulation seems like a great focus area in this day of JSON.

Answer (score 5):

Yes;  completely possible.   See the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for details (including the related guides & docs).

As Justin said, it is extremely atypical to go this route.   If you are loading XML data, it is almost always the cast that said XML must have a well defined structure -- a strict DTD or schema -- and, thus, you would be much better off with a disciplined, well defined, data model compiled into your app (via Core Data or direct implementation) that you load the XML against.   This allows for tighter validation and will be significantly easier.

The holy grail of "free form data consumption" is oft tempting, but down that path lies madness and many tales of woe.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you *can* use the objc runtime to create a type, define methods and its storage-- all at runtime... it's very unusual to do this, however.

the interfaces you use are in the runtime headers `objc/runtime.h`, and the calls you want are  `objc_allocateClassPair`, `class_addMethod`, `class_addIvar`, etc. there's obviously quite a bit of work to be done in order create a class and its layout, selectors, and such from an XML description. Therefore, yes it is possible, but it's not free.

Comment: You *have* to expand on this :)

Comment: @Tim Kemp lol - I was simply answering 'Is it possible to define classes at run time in objective-c?' -- but I've expanded on it now =)