# Accessing property of an object from the string which contains its name

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have a `NSString *str = @"abc"` and an object which has a property with name 'abc'. How can I access that property using 'str'. I know I have to use objective-c runtime, but dont know if its even possible. I dont want to set that property, instead I want to use that property like if propert 'abc' is an array than I want to add an object to that array. I have gone through

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565665/objective-c-classes-runtime-definition) link and found it little helpful to start over.

Comment: One option could be simply adding all the strings to a dictionary and then polling the values based on `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a given property given only a string by calling `valueForKey:`.  If, however, you wish to mutate an array associated with that key, a call to `mutableArrayValueForKey:` will give you access to an array that calls the appropriate mutator methods on the original object (or even give you the object itself, but those are implementation details) when you mutate it.

Comment: Hey thanks it helped alot but i just need one more thing, is their any way to check the class of object returned form valueForKey method? I just wana check if that object belongs to a particular class like NSMutableArray, but [obj isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]  always return NO, maybe cuz obj is nil as we have not set it yet.

Comment: It's because the object returned from valueForKey: and it's variants might be a proxy KVO created for you.  You shouldn't be doing unchecked keypath fetches anyhow.  If you can't reliably access the property to guarantee it's type, don't use KVC.

Comment: I know the property returned will be either of NSMutableArray or some other objective C object. If its not a NSMutableArray, i will directly set that property,  and if its an NSMutableArray, than i will  alloc init that property and  and addObjects. Thats why I want to know the type of property returned.

Comment: But I'm trying to tell you that even though KVC returns a proxy object representing an array, that the proxy might not be a subclass of NSMutableArray.  You can't rely on type checking for objects returned from KVC, so you have to rely on type checking for the property itself.

Comment: for now i am alloc init all the NSMutableArray properties in my model class in its init method, so i can check [obj isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]] cuz than it wont be nil.

Answer (score 3):

To do this you will want to use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html):

> This document describes the `NSKeyValueCoding` informal protocol, which defines a mechanism allowing applications to access the properties of an object indirectly by name (or key), rather than directly through invocation of an accessor method or as instance variables.